# How to insert number in 2d list?

Tags: python

How can I insert a value, here 99, into the indices 1 producing [3,4,99] ?

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

x.insert(1[1],99)   #this gives back  'int' object is not subscriptable

print(x)
```

Comment: do you want to insert or append?

Answer (score 3):

Append the element to the list element index 1 with `x[1].append(99)`.

```
>>> x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> x[1].append(99)
>>> print(x)
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 99], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

given the list:

`x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

if you want to insert an element in the middle of the `[3,4]` element:

`x[1].insert(1, 3.5)`

will return you

```
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 3.5, 4], [5, 6]]
```

if you want to add anything to the end of a list, the method for that is `append`:

`x[1].append(5)`

now you have:

```
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 3.5, 4, 5], [5, 6]]
```